# Manually implement simple scroll like behaviour in android

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll, touch, scrollview

First of all I can't use Scrollviews, its overkill for my need,

I want to just move a view vertically when drag using finger,I am able to achieve that using the following code,

```
    float dY;         @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:              
            dY = getY() - event.getRawY();
            return false;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float distance = event.getRawY() + dY ;
            animate()                     
                    .y(distance)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


}
```

But the problem is, it doesn't act like scrolling, Simply I just want vertical scroll like behavior without using scrollview or any other parent views , nothing else!

I referred  [this](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll#java), but didn't get the point...

I searched a lot in the net, I found Scroller, Custom scrollview, etc,  but no simple solution! I am surprised on that. I can't use any parent views, I just want to implement using touch event, any simpler solution?

Comment: `ScrollView` is there because scrolling is not simple. Even supporting scrolling just a single child view, `ScrollView` is [over 1,900 lines](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java) and `NestedScrolView` is [2,100+ lines of code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView.java).

Comment: So far what I understand is, scrolling is a very complex mechanism. If that so, can we just extract the code just what I want? (Without multiple child management, without extra stuff)

Comment: Move a view like scrolling, no scrollviews should be added! :(

Comment: ok you want scrolling, do you know what `ScrollView` is used for?

Comment: I know that, I even know scroller, but I am in a situation that no scrollviews & parent views  can be used!

Comment: what situation? you have a view without a parent? where do you have `onTouchEvent` method?

Comment: Situation: One root view + only one child view(MyView), MyView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { <above code> });

Comment: what is `MyView`? what `ViewGroup` is it added to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181527/discussion-between-jaya-prakash-and-pskink).